# Joey wearing pants - is it realistic?

Tags: plot-explanation, historical-accuracy, el-dorado

In "El Dorado", Joey McDonald, the daughter of Kevin McDonald, is wearing pants whenever she rides a horse. Was it socially acceptable for a girl to wear pants in the Wild West?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely. There's very little writing on the subject, which in itself could be considered evidence that it wasn't *so outrageous*, but we do have a lot of photographs of frontierswomen wearing trousers, most of which I can find are from the book [Women in Pants: Manly Maidens, Cowgirls, and Other Renegades](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002RQ1IG):

- [Calamity Jane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calamity_Jane)

  Professional scout and known for fighting Indians as well as her claim that she knew [Wild Bill Hickok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Bill_Hickok), both of whom were immortalised in [Deadwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadwood_%28TV_series%29). This image is from 1895:

  [image: Image of Calamity Jane]
- [Stella, Bertha and Mabel Sweet and Maybel Davis](http://www.nps.gov/yose/historyculture/women.htm)

  These 4 were the third group of women to climb [Mt. Lyell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Lyell_%28California%29) and the first to descend into [Tuolumne Canyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canyon_of_the_Tuolumne), this image from 1896 has them in leggings and [bloomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomers_%28clothing%29#Athletic_bloomers_.28unskirted.29):

  [image: Image of Stella, Bertha and Mabel Sweet and Maybel Davis]

There are also images of unknown women in trousers from the era, for example the name of this 1880s Arizona Scout has been lost, but it does suggest that men and women both wore the same type of clothing, as clearly a dress is not appropriate for battle or sleeping in the wilderness.

[image: Image of a female scout from Arizona]

Comment: Great explanation!